# The final cost is not calculated when choosing the weight of the product if the packaging is automatically added in WooCommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce

In WooCommerce, I use a code that shows the steak weight selection form, saves the selection data and displays this data in the cart, on the checkout page, when editing the order and in email notifications.

```
// Display Custom Checkbox Field
add_action('woocommerce_product_options_general_product_data', 'steak_custom_field_add');
function steak_custom_field_add(){
    global $post;

    // Checkbox
    woocommerce_wp_checkbox(
        array(
            'id' => '_steak_checkbox',
            'label' => __('Steak Weight', 'woocommerce' ),
            'description' => __( 'If necessary, enable steak weight selection', 'woocommerce' )
        )
    );
}

// Save Custom Checkbox Field
add_action('woocommerce_process_product_meta', 'steak_custom_field_save');
function steak_custom_field_save($post_id){
    // Custom Product Checkbox Field
    $steak_checkbox = isset( $_POST['_steak_checkbox'] ) ? 'yes' : 'no';
    update_post_meta($post_id, '_steak_checkbox', esc_attr( $steak_checkbox ));
}

// Display Custom Select Box
add_action( 'woocommerce_before_add_to_cart_button', 'display_steak_custom_field', 0 );
function display_steak_custom_field() {
    global $product;

    // If is single product page and have the "steak_checkbox" enabled we display the field
    if ( $product->get_meta( '_steak_checkbox' ) === 'yes' ) {

        echo '<div class="steak_select_box">';

        $select = woocommerce_form_field( 'steak_custom_options', array(
            'type'          => 'select',
            'class'         => array('my-steak-select-box form-row-wide'),
            'label'         => __('Steak Weight'),
            'required'      => false,
            'return'       => false,
            'options'   => array(
                ''      => 'Select...',
                '300g'  => '300g',
                '400g'  => '400g',
                '500g'  => '500g',
                '600g'  => '600g',
                '700g'  => '700g',
                '800g'  => '800g',
                '900g'  => '900g',
                '1000g'  => '1000g'
            )
        ), '' );
        echo $select;
        echo '</div>';
    }
}

// Add as custom cart item data
add_filter( 'woocommerce_add_cart_item_data', 'add_custom_steak_cart_item_data', 10, 21 );
function add_custom_steak_cart_item_data($cart_item_data, $product_id, $variation_id ){

    if( isset( $_POST['steak_custom_options'] ) ) {
        $cart_item_data['steak_option'] = wc_clean( $_POST['steak_custom_options'] );
    }
    return $cart_item_data;
}

// Add custom fields values under cart item name in cart
add_filter( 'woocommerce_cart_item_name', 'steak_custom_field_add_cart', 10, 21 );
function steak_custom_field_add_cart( $item_name, $cart_item, $cart_item_key ) {
    if( ! is_cart() )
        return $item_name;

    if( isset($cart_item['steak_option']) ) {
        $item_name .= '<div class="my-steak-class"><strong>' . __("Steak Weight", "woocommerce") . ':</strong> ' . $cart_item['steak_option'] . '</div>';
    }
    return $item_name;
}

// Display custom fields values under item name in checkout
add_filter( 'woocommerce_checkout_cart_item_quantity', 'steak_custom_checkout_cart_item_name', 10, 21 );
function steak_custom_checkout_cart_item_name( $item_qty, $cart_item, $cart_item_key ) {
    if( isset($cart_item['steak_option']) ) {
        $item_qty .= '<div class="my-steak-class"><strong>' . __("Steak Weight", "woocommerce") . ':</strong> ' . $cart_item['steak_option'] . 'гр.</div>';
    }
    return $item_qty;
}


// Save chosen select field value to each order item as custom meta data and display it everywhere
add_action('woocommerce_checkout_create_order_line_item', 'save_order_item_steak_field', 10, 21 );
function save_order_item_steak_field( $item, $cart_item_key, $values, $order ) {
    if( isset($values['steak_option']) ) {
        $key = __('Steak Weight', 'woocommerce');
        $value = $values['steak_option'];
        $item->update_meta_data( $key, $value ,$item->get_id());
    }
}

add_action('wp_footer','add_footer_steak_script');
function add_footer_steak_script(){
    ?>
    <script>
       ( function( $ ) {
   $( document ).ready( function() {
       $(document).on('change', '#steak_custom_options' ,function() {
           $('.add_to_cart_button').data('steak_custom_options', this.value)
       });
   });
 }( jQuery ) );
    </script>
    <?php
}

add_action( 'woocommerce_before_calculate_totals', 'my_before_calculate_totals', 10, 1 );
    function my_before_calculate_totals( $cart ) {
    if ( is_admin() && ! defined( 'DOING_AJAX' ) )
        return;

    if ( did_action( 'woocommerce_before_calculate_totals' ) >= 2 )
        return;

    // Loop through cart items
    foreach ( $cart->get_cart() as $cart_item_key => $cart_item ) {     
        if( isset( $cart_item['steak_option'] ) ) {

            // Remove the last 2 zeros (100g becomes 1, 300g becomes 3, 1000g becomes 10, etc...)
            // Remove 'g' from grams
            // convert string to integer
            $chosen_weight = (int) str_replace( '00', '', str_replace('g', '', $cart_item['steak_option']) );

            // Get current price
            $current_price = $cart_item['data']->get_price();

            // Set new price, price is already known per 100g
            $cart_item['data']->set_price( $current_price * $chosen_weight );
        }
    }
}

add_action('wp_footer','add_footer_steak_script');
    function add_footer_steak_script() {
    global $woocommerce, $product;
    ?>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {
            console.log('JS works!');

            var price = <?php echo $product->get_price(); ?>, currency = '<?php echo get_woocommerce_currency_symbol(); ?>';

            $( '[name=steak_custom_options]' ).change(function(){
                if (!(this.value < 1)) {
                    var dropdown_val = this.value;
                    var remove_g = dropdown_val.replace( 'g', '' );
                    var remove_double_zero = remove_g.replace( '00', '' );

                    var product_total = parseFloat( price * remove_double_zero );

                    $( '.woocommerce-Price-amount' ).html( currency + product_total.toFixed(2));

                }
            });
        });
    </script>
    <?php
}
```

I also use a code that automatically adds packaging when adding any dish to the cart.

```
 /**
 * Calculate the number of lunchboxes and package, based on the number of products in cart.
 */ 
function add_delivery_charge_to_cart( $cart ) {
    if ( is_admin() && ! defined( 'DOING_AJAX' ) )
        return;

    if ( did_action( 'woocommerce_before_calculate_totals' ) >= 2 )
        return;

    /********** SETTINGS **********/

    $lunchbox_id  = 5737; // "LunchBox ID" to be added to cart
    $pakket_id = 5738; // "Pakket ID" to be added to cart
    $exclude_categories = array( 'drink', 'bread' ); // Exclude these categories

    $category_qty_total = 0; // Total of category quantity items, Don't edit!!

    /********** LOOP THROUGH CART ITEMS **********/

    foreach ( $cart->get_cart() as $cart_item_key => $cart_item ) {
        // Get product id
        $product_id = $cart_item['data']->get_id();

        // Get product quantity
        $product_qty = $cart_item['quantity'];

        // Check if "LunchBox" product is already in cart
        if( $product_id == $lunchbox_id ) {
            $lunchbox_key = $cart_item_key;
            $lunchbox_qty = $product_qty;
        }

        // Check if "Pakket" product is already in cart
        if( $product_id == $pakket_id ) {
            $pakket_key = $cart_item_key;
            $pakket_qty = $product_qty;
        }

        // Check if product belongs to a certain category
        if( has_term( $exclude_categories, 'product_cat', $product_id ) ) {
            $category_qty_total += $product_qty;
        }
    }

    /********** CALCULATE THE TOTALS, SO "LUNCHBOX", "PAKKET" & CATEGORIES ARE NOT USED IN THE TOTALS **********/

    // Get total items in cart, counts number of products & quantity per product
    $total_items_in_cart = $cart->get_cart_contents_count();

    // Total items in cart - category quantity total
    $total_items_in_cart -= $category_qty_total;

    // Lunchbox total = total_items_in_cart & pakket total = total_items_in_cart 
    $lunchbox_total = $total_items_in_cart;
    $pakket_total = $total_items_in_cart;

    // Isset lunchbox qty -> lunchbox total - lunchbox qty & pakket total - lunchbox qty
    if ( isset($lunchbox_qty) ) {
        $lunchbox_total -= $lunchbox_qty;
        $pakket_total -= $lunchbox_qty;     
    }

    // Isset pakket qty -> lunchbox total - pakket qty & pakket total - pakket qty   
    if ( isset($pakket_qty) ) {
        $lunchbox_total -= $pakket_qty;
        $pakket_total = $pakket_total - $pakket_qty;
    }

    /********** APPLY NEW TOTALS TO LUNCHBOX & PAKKET **********/

    // If product "LunchBox" is in cart, we check the quantity to update it if needed
    if ( isset($lunchbox_key) && $lunchbox_qty != $total_items_in_cart ) {
        // Set quantity, lunchbox
        $cart->set_quantity( $lunchbox_key, $lunchbox_total );

    } elseif ( !isset($lunchbox_key) && $total_items_in_cart > 0 ) {
        // Product "LunchBox" is not in cart, we add it
        $cart->add_to_cart( $lunchbox_id, $total_items_in_cart );
    }

    // Total items in cart greater than or equal to 3
    if ( $total_items_in_cart >= 3 ) {
        // Pakket total = pakket_total / 3 = floor(result)
        // Floor = round fractions down, rounding result down
        $pakket_total = floor( $pakket_total / 3 );

        // If product "Pakket" is in cart
        if ( isset($pakket_key) ) {
            // Set quantity, pakket
            $cart->set_quantity( $pakket_key, $pakket_total );

        } elseif ( !isset($pakket_key) ) {
            // Product "Pakket" is not in cart, we add it
            $cart->add_to_cart( $pakket_id, $pakket_total );
        }
    }
}
add_action( 'woocommerce_before_calculate_totals', 'add_delivery_charge_to_cart', 10, 1 );
```

Unfortunately, these two codes conflict with each other and I cannot understand what is the reason.

1. If the packaging is added, the total amount when choosing the weight of the product is not calculated.
2. In the cart and on the checkout page, the data "Steak Weight: 300g" is added to the package. And this data should not be there.

How can this be fixed? I will be happy for your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using the same hook `woocommerce_before_calculate_totals` twice will indeed cause problems, so it is a matter of **combining both codes into one function**.

As the code is written now there are some conditions

- pakket_id & lunchbox_id products may not be used in any other way! these are added automatically and therefore cannot be added by a user/guest on your website
- products belonging to the excluded categories may not contain the weight option with dropdown menu (same condition for pakket & lunchbox product)

---

> **NOTE:** With this piece of code I also added the lunchbox ID, otherwise
>   you will receive a notification of the weight under the lunchbox
>   product, in some cases.
>
> ```php
> // Add as custom cart item data
> function add_custom_steak_cart_item_data( $cart_item_data, $product_id, $variation_id, $quantity ) {  
>     if ( !empty( $_POST['steak_custom_options'] ) && $product_id != 5737 ) {
>     ...
> ```

---

So then you get

```php
// Display Custom Checkbox Field
function steak_custom_field_add() {
    global $post;

    // Checkbox
    woocommerce_wp_checkbox(
        array(
            'id' => '_steak_checkbox',
            'label' => __('Steak Weight', 'woocommerce' ),
            'description' => __( 'If necessary, enable steak weight selection', 'woocommerce' )
        )
    );
}
add_action('woocommerce_product_options_general_product_data', 'steak_custom_field_add', 10, 0 );

// Save Custom Checkbox Field
function steak_custom_field_save( $post_id ) {
    $product = wc_get_product( $post_id );

    // Custom Product Checkbox Field
    $steak_checkbox = isset( $_POST['_steak_checkbox'] ) ? 'yes' : 'no';

    // Update product meta
    $product->update_meta_data( '_steak_checkbox', $steak_checkbox );

    // Save
    $product->save();
}
add_action('woocommerce_process_product_meta', 'steak_custom_field_save', 10, 1 );

// Display Custom Select Box
function display_steak_custom_field() {
    global $post;

    // Get product
    $product = wc_get_product( $post->ID );

    // If is single product page and have the "steak_checkbox" enabled we display the field
    if ( $product->get_meta( '_steak_checkbox' ) === 'yes' ) {

        echo '<div class="steak_select_box">';

        $select = woocommerce_form_field( 'steak_custom_options', array(
            'type'          => 'select',
            'class'         => array('my-steak-select-box form-row-wide'),
            'label'         => __('Steak Weight'),
            'required'      => false,
            'return'       => false,
            'options'   => array(
                ''      => 'Select...',
                '300g'  => '300g',
                '400g'  => '400g',
                '500g'  => '500g',
                '600g'  => '600g',
                '700g'  => '700g',
                '800g'  => '800g',
                '900g'  => '900g',
                '1000g'  => '1000g'
            )
        ), '' );
        echo $select;
        echo '</div>';
    }
}
add_action( 'woocommerce_before_add_to_cart_button', 'display_steak_custom_field', 10, 0 );

// Add jQuery script to footer - change price on single product page
function add_footer_steak_script() {
    // Returns true on a single product page
    if ( is_product() ) {
        global $woocommerce, $product;
        ?>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {
                var price = <?php echo $product->get_price(); ?>, currency = '<?php echo get_woocommerce_currency_symbol(); ?>';

                $( '[name=steak_custom_options]' ).change(function(){
                    if (!(this.value < 1)) {
                        var dropdown_val = this.value;
                        var remove_g = dropdown_val.replace( 'g', '' );
                        var remove_double_zero = remove_g.replace( '00', '' );

                        var product_total = parseFloat( price * remove_double_zero );

                        $( '.woocommerce-Price-amount' ).html( currency + product_total.toFixed(2));

                    }
                });
            });
        </script>
        <?php
    }
}
add_action('wp_footer','add_footer_steak_script', 10, 0 );

// Add as custom cart item data
function add_custom_steak_cart_item_data( $cart_item_data, $product_id, $variation_id, $quantity ) {    
    if ( !empty( $_POST['steak_custom_options'] ) && $product_id != 5737 ) {
        $cart_item_data['steak_option'] = $_POST['steak_custom_options'];
    }

    return $cart_item_data;
}
add_filter( 'woocommerce_add_cart_item_data', 'add_custom_steak_cart_item_data', 10, 4 );

// Add custom fields values under cart item name in cart
function steak_custom_field_add_cart( $item_name, $cart_item, $cart_item_key ) {    
    if( is_cart() ) {
        if( isset( $cart_item['steak_option'] ) ) {
            $item_name .= '<div class="my-steak-class"><strong>' . __("Steak Weight", "woocommerce") . ':</strong> ' . $cart_item['steak_option'] . '</div>';
        }
    }

    return $item_name;
}
add_filter( 'woocommerce_cart_item_name', 'steak_custom_field_add_cart', 10, 3 );

/**
 * Calculate the number of lunchboxes and package, based on the number of products in cart.
 */
function add_delivery_charge_to_cart( $cart ) {
    if ( is_admin() && ! defined( 'DOING_AJAX' ) )
        return;

    if ( did_action( 'woocommerce_before_calculate_totals' ) >= 2 )
        return;

    /********** SETTINGS **********/

    $lunchbox_id  = 5737; // "LunchBox ID" to be added to cart
    $pakket_id = 5738; // "Pakket ID" to be added to cart
    $exclude_categories = array( 'drink', 'bread' ); // Exclude these categories

    $category_qty_total = 0; // Total of category quantity items, Don't edit!!

    /********** LOOP THROUGH CART ITEMS **********/

    foreach ( $cart->get_cart() as $cart_item_key => $cart_item ) {     
        // Get product id
        $product_id = $cart_item['data']->get_id();

        // Get product quantity
        $product_qty = $cart_item['quantity'];

        // Check if "LunchBox" product is already in cart
        if( $product_id == $lunchbox_id ) {
            $lunchbox_key = $cart_item_key;
            $lunchbox_qty = $product_qty;
        }

        // Check if "Pakket" product is already in cart
        if( $product_id == $pakket_id ) {
            $pakket_key = $cart_item_key;
            $pakket_qty = $product_qty;
        }

        // Check if product belongs to a certain category
        if( has_term( $exclude_categories, 'product_cat', $product_id ) ) {
            $category_qty_total += $product_qty;
        }

        // Check if product, contains steak weight
        if( isset( $cart_item['steak_option'] ) ) {
            // Remove the last 2 zeros (100g becomes 1, 300g becomes 3, 1000g becomes 10, etc...)
            // Remove 'g' from grams
            // convert string to integer
            $chosen_weight = (int) str_replace( '00', '', str_replace('g', '', $cart_item['steak_option']) );

            // Get current price
            $current_price = $cart_item['data']->get_price();

            // Set new price, price is already known per 100g
            $cart_item['data']->set_price( $current_price * $chosen_weight );
        }
    }

    /********** CALCULATE THE TOTALS, SO "LUNCHBOX", "PAKKET" & CATEGORIES ARE NOT USED IN THE TOTALS **********/

    // Get total items in cart, counts number of products & quantity per product
    $total_items_in_cart = $cart->get_cart_contents_count();

    // Total items in cart - category quantity total
    $total_items_in_cart -= $category_qty_total;

    // Lunchbox total = total_items_in_cart & pakket total = total_items_in_cart 
    $lunchbox_total = $total_items_in_cart;
    $pakket_total = $total_items_in_cart;

    // Isset lunchbox qty -> lunchbox total - lunchbox qty & pakket total - lunchbox qty
    if ( isset($lunchbox_qty) ) {
        $lunchbox_total -= $lunchbox_qty;
        $pakket_total -= $lunchbox_qty;     
    }

    // Isset pakket qty -> lunchbox total - pakket qty & pakket total - pakket qty   
    if ( isset($pakket_qty) ) {
        $lunchbox_total -= $pakket_qty;
        $pakket_total = $pakket_total - $pakket_qty;
    }

    /********** APPLY NEW TOTALS TO LUNCHBOX & PAKKET **********/

    // If product "LunchBox" is in cart, we check the quantity to update it if needed
    if ( isset($lunchbox_key) && $lunchbox_qty != $total_items_in_cart ) {
        // Set quantity, lunchbox
        $cart->set_quantity( $lunchbox_key, $lunchbox_total );

    } elseif ( !isset($lunchbox_key) && $total_items_in_cart > 0 ) {
        // Product "LunchBox" is not in cart, we add it
        $cart->add_to_cart( $lunchbox_id, $total_items_in_cart );
    }

    // Total items in cart greater than or equal to 3
    if ( $total_items_in_cart >= 3 ) {
        // Pakket total = pakket_total / 3 = floor(result)
        // Floor = round fractions down, rounding result down
        $pakket_total = floor( $pakket_total / 3 );

        // If product "Pakket" is in cart
        if ( isset($pakket_key) ) {
            // Set quantity, pakket
            $cart->set_quantity( $pakket_key, $pakket_total );

        } elseif ( !isset($pakket_key) ) {
            // Product "Pakket" is not in cart, we add it
            $cart->add_to_cart( $pakket_id, $pakket_total );
        }
    }
}
add_action( 'woocommerce_before_calculate_totals', 'add_delivery_charge_to_cart', 10, 1 );

// Display custom fields values under item name in checkout
function steak_custom_checkout_cart_item_name( $item_qty, $cart_item, $cart_item_key ) {    
    if( isset($cart_item['steak_option']) ) {
        $item_qty .= '<div class="my-steak-class"><strong>' . __("Steak Weight", "woocommerce") . ':</strong> ' . $cart_item['steak_option'] . 'гр.</div>';
    }
    return $item_qty;
}
add_filter( 'woocommerce_checkout_cart_item_quantity', 'steak_custom_checkout_cart_item_name', 10, 3 );

// Save chosen select field value to each order item as custom meta data and display it everywhere
function save_order_item_steak_field( $item, $cart_item_key, $values, $order ) {
    if( isset($values['steak_option']) ) {
        $key = __('Steak Weight', 'woocommerce');
        $value = $values['steak_option'];
        $item->update_meta_data( $key, $value ,$item->get_id());
    }
}
add_action('woocommerce_checkout_create_order_line_item', 'save_order_item_steak_field', 10, 4 );
```